# Is it possible to use multiple gitlab runners for one CI build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

There is a project which has a lot of tests, and running them all takes about 20 minutes. Unfortunately, it is not possible to parallel them inside one gitlab runner. I wonder if there are any good practices to start multiple gitlab runners with the same environment but different test suits?

Comment: When you say "one CI build", do you mean that you are able to split the test suit into multiple parts or not?

Comment: @cascaval yes, I mean that when I push changes to gitlab it should start build doing tests in parallel runners. Actually, I found a way to do this through jobs and stages (http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#jobs). But I think there is a more elegant way.

Comment: That's what I was about to suggest to you when I started writing my answer and then stopped because I wasn't sure whether you don't expect a single job to be run by multiple runners with some magical distinction of what each of them is supposed to complete. I now added my answer which also points to some configuration so that it works as you expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can split the test suit into several parts, you can create equal number of jobs in the same stage (*test*). **Jobs in the same stage are run in parallel** but jobs in the next stage will start after the jobs of the previous stage complete. **They will run in parallel even if you have only one runner.** Let's assume this test case:

```
stages:
  - test

testsA:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sleep 60
    - echo 'Test set A done'

testsB:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sleep 30
    - echo 'Test set B done'
```

You will see that they are running at the same time and test A will complete after test B.

Adjust the runners' [settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) (*/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml*) checking for 2 options:

- `concurrent` = the total number of jobs run in parallel across all runners
- `limit` (set for each runner) = the number of jobs run in parallel by one particular runner

Note: I haven't tested if a project with multiple runners, each of them having `limit` set to 1, would run these jobs using different runners. However, I assume it works this way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `concurrent` option, that was the failure in my configuration

Comment: You can find the file on in `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`